# How to get a comma-separated list of pages with color in a PDF?

Tags: list, pdf, sed, grep, ghostscript

Consider this PDF 'colorpages.pdf' linked *[here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x8dczvsj66p1si6/colorpages.pdf?dl=1)*

I have two commands to know 
a) how many colored pages I have in my PDF
b) on which page color is used.

For a) I use

```
gs -o - -sDEVICE=inkcov colorpages.pdf | grep -v "^ 0.00000  0.00000  0.00000" | grep "^ " | wc
```

and I get back a number (total amount of pages with color).

For b) I use

```
gs -o - -sDEVICE=inkcov  colorpages.pdf |tail -n +5 |sed '/^Page*/N;s/\n//' |sed -E '/Page [0-9]+ 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 / d'
```

which gives me a nice list with color information; e.g.

```
Page 1 0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.99454 CMYK OK
Page 2 0.00000  0.99228  0.00000  0.00000 CMYK OK
Page 3 0.99222  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 CMYK OK
Page 4 0.99289  0.99289  0.99289  0.99289 CMYK OK
Page 5 0.99316  0.99316  0.00000  0.00000 CMYK OK
Page 6 0.99130  0.99130  0.99130  0.99130 CMYK OK
Page 7 0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.99392 CMYK OK
Page 8 0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.99189 CMYK OK
Page 9 0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.99128 CMYK OK
Page 10 0.00000  0.00000  0.98594  0.00000 CMYK OK
Page 11 0.00000  0.98908  0.98908  0.00000 CMYK OK
Page 12 0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.98682 CMYK OK
```

But what I need (additionally) is a *comma separated list* of all the pages color is used.

---

### Following up

The command

```
gs -o - -sDEVICE=inkcov colorpages.pdf |tail -n +5 |sed '/^Page*/N;s/\n//' |sed -E '/Page [0-9]+ 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 / d' | awk '$3!=0 && $4!=0 && $5!=0{if(length(colored))colored=colored","$2;else colored=$2} END{print colored}'
```

gives me the following list `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12`.
But it should be 2,3,4,5,6,10,11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '$3!=0{if(length(colored))colored=colored","$2;else colored=$2} END{print colored}'
2,5,7




 -->echo "$x"
Page 1 0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.12395 CMYK OK
Page 2 0.00016  0.00035  0.00017  0.47061 CMYK OK
Page 3 0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.34571 CMYK OK
Page 4 0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.32637 CMYK OK
Page 5 0.00016  0.00035  0.00017  0.47061 CMYK OK
Page 6 0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.63394 CMYK OK
Page 7 0.00016  0.00035  0.00017  0.47061 CMYK OK


echo "$x" |awk '$3!=0{if(length(colored))colored=colored","$2;else colored=$2} END{print colored}'
2,5,7
```

If col 3,4,5 needs to be `0` to call a row colored then :(you can play around with these conditions)

```
awk '$3!=0 &&  $4!=0 && $5!=0{if(length(colored))colored=colored","$2;else colored=$2} END{print colored}'
```

*Update*:

You can use OR operator(`||`) to get the desired result as mentioned in the question.

```
echo "$x" |awk '$3!=0 ||  $4!=0 || $5!=0{if(length(colored))colored=colored","$2;else colored=$2} END{print colored}'
2,3,4,5,6,10,11
```

Comment: Could you please tell me where to input your code with the Ghostscript-commands?
With `gs -o - -sDEVICE=inkcov MY-PDF.pdf |tail -n +5 |sed '/^Page*/N;s/\n//' |sed -E '/Page [0-9]+ 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 / d' | awk '$3!=0{if(length(colored))colored=colored","$2;else colored=$2} END{print colored}'` (taking the example above) I get `1,2,3,4,5,6,7`

Comment: the awk command is checking for 3rd column , if its not equal to zero. Its assuming that its colored row and printing the page number , so with the input provided by you it has returned 2,5,7 . You are putting the command at right place.

Comment: strange. I still get the same result with all pages listed.

Comment: I realised that there can also be a row like `Page 7 0.00000  0.00021  0.00021  0.34524 CMYK OK`, which would lead to a false result with your solution. It should be considered whether column 3, 4 or 5 is unequal 0.

Comment: what is the condition for a row to be called colored ? col 3,4,5 should be 0 ? I have updated answer to add this case. You can modify the answer as per requirement, by modifying the conditional statements.

Comment: I updated my question and added a PDF. Still I get a list with all pages. A page is considered colored if column 3, 4 or 5 is UNEQUAL 0. So your command does the right thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189480/discussion-between-lukascb-and-ps).

Comment: I am not sure, but this command is generating the desired result for me. awk '$3!=0 ||  $4!=0 || $5!=0{if(length(colored))colored=colored","$2;else colored=$2} END{print colored}'
2,3,4,5,6,10,11

Comment: must be due to some macOS-issue. I tested it with Linux and it worked - so I have to figure out what is the difference to macOS’s awk.

Comment: on Mac try instead of  `$3 != 0` use `$3!="0.00000"` , or `$3 != 0.00000` like wise . I am guessing

Comment: YEAH!!! Finally! thank you very much! `$3!="0.00000"` was the solution.